# What are our policies about this exotic I/O format about integers?

Tags: discussion, policy

Please refer to [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26010/89459) on Sandbox. (**EDIT:** The challenge is [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265809/89459) on main.)

Basically, the proposed challenge is about a new numeral system I made. Though the proposal doesn't *require* the I/O format to be in the numeral system, I have a serious problem now: **This opens new possibility for an I/O format about integers.**

AFAIK, our default policies about I/O formats don't stop from inputting/outputting integers in this new format. We even allow using different formats for the input and the output.

Though I've just prohibited I/O in NDos-numeral as a stopgap, there might appear new programming languages whose default I/O format for integers is NDos-numeral, and I *hope* that would be considered a standard loophole.

What should I do?

Comment: where do you see something that suggests this format is allowed by default?  Could you add that to the question.  It seems like important context.

Comment: I think it is already a standard loophole by the rule of not using number systems that trivialize a challenge—if it's easier in NDos-notation, NDos notation would probably trigger this rule unless the OP encourages/explicitly allows it (like I did in my recent question).

Comment: The language would have been created after the challenge, so it would be an invalid answer.